# How to get Squid to not cache files with certain extensions?

Tags: proxy, cache, squid

I've found information on how to keep squid from caching domains/IP addresses, however, that's not quite what I want.  I'd like to prevent it from caching *.jnlp* and *.jar* files.

The core problem being that when I push updates out to our server, our users that are behind a squid proxy may not get the updated version for several days (apparently it takes that long for squid to figure out that the files have changed).  Perhaps I've missed an even easier solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this in your conf:

```
acl DENYZIP urlpath_regex \.zip
no_cache deny DENYZIP
```

You could, of course, make a much more sophisticated regex that would handle multiple files (and change the acl name accordingly).

Comment: Hmmm, can't quite get this to work as written.  Blows up with regex errors.  Trying re-writes with a true regex.

Comment: Bah, yeah my bad.  *.zip is a "brain-on-auto-pilot" typo...  Edited to remove the *.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC you do this by setting up `refresh_pattern` rules in your `squid.conf` file.  This matches URL's by regex and sets caching policies for the matches.  The reference manual describes it [here.](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid30/tuning.php#refresh_pattern)

Note that the refresh_pattern rules apply only to responses without an explicit expiration time.

Answer (score 2):

If your **squid version** is **3.3 and higher** then you should

```
acl DENYZIP urlpath_regex \.zip
cache deny DENYZIP
```

Because **no_cache** directive replaced by **cache**